# Refactor @click.option() arguments

Tags: python, python-click

Say I have this (minimal example from a larger script):

```
import click

@click.command()
@click.option('--foo', required=True)
def bar1(foo: str) -> None:
    print(f"bar1: {foo}")

@click.command()
@click.option('--foo', required=True)
def bar2(foo: str) -> None:
    print(f"bar2: {foo}")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    bar1() # these are actually called from a poetry scripts section in pyproject.toml
    # bar2()
```

I would like to avoid repeating the same option `--foo` with the same arguments for both `bar1` and `bar2`. Maybe something like

```
@click.option(*ClickOptions.foo)
```

but this does not work since option foo also takes keyword argument `required=True`. I would like to avoid splitting it up like this:

```
@click.option(*ClickOptions.foo.args, **ClickOptions.foo.kwargs)
```

Is there an elegant way to do this?

Comment: The most straightforward I see is to simply define your own decorator or decorator factory function.

Comment: @LouisLac I tried this and I get error "Error: No such option: --foo", see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77169006/creating-a-wrapper-decorator-for-click-options

Comment: The question you link has an accepted answer, why is the issue?

Answer (score 1):

To expand on @Louis Lac's response, I defined my own decorator like this, which you can use like any other decorator on the group/command

```py
_global_options = [
    click.option('-v', '--verbose', count=True, default=0, help='Verbose output.'),
    click.option('-n', '--dry-run', is_flag=True, default=False, help='Dry-run mode.')
]


def common_options(func):
    for option in reversed(_global_options):
        func = option(func)
    return func

@click.group()
@common_options
def cli(**kwargs):
    pass
```