# Creating a wrapper decorator for click.options()

Tags: python, python-decorators, python-click

I am trying to create a wrapper decorator for the click decorator `@click.options('--foo', required=True)`:

```
import click

def foo_option(func):
    orig_decorator = click.option('--foo', required=True)(func)
    def decorator(*args, **kwargs):
        orig_decorator(*args, **kwargs)
    return decorator

@click.command()
@foo_option
def bar1(foo: str) -> None:
    print(f"bar1: {foo}")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    bar1()
```

This does not work. When I run it like `script.py --foo=1` I get error:

```
Usage: script.py [OPTIONS]
Try 'script.py --help' for help.

Error: No such option: --foo
```

Expected output should be:

```
bar1: 1
```

What am I missing?
See [Refactor @click.option() arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77168894/2173773) for background information.

Comment: What's the point of `decorator` here? It seems like you just want a `functools.partial`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Maybe it should be called `wrapper` ? It should wrap the click decorator wrapper

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is with how you have structured the decorator. In this case, you are wrapping around the click.option which is unnecessary. When you create a decorator to wrap around another decorator (like click.option), you should consider that decorators work from bottom to top. here is the updated code:

```
import click


def foo_option(func):
    return click.option('--foo', required=True)(func)


@click.command()
@foo_option
def bar1(foo: str) -> None:
    print(f"bar1: {foo}")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    bar1()
```

When you run the script, you will get the expected output.